# Data conversion error when using floor function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

please help me on this.

i am trying to check if .two decimal value not in a column using this.

```
FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(M.Description_12_Value)+1)))+1 <> 2
```

but i am getting error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8.5' to data
>   type int.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the part which generated error. Can you post full query if possible

Comment: Which is your DBMS and which is the version of your DBMS? I also agree with @Indian that you have to post entire query.

Comment: Hello, i have posted the query. i am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Try cast to float => `FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(CAST(M.Description_12_Value AS FLOAT))+1)))+1 <> 2`

Comment: Cast to float not working. same error

Comment: Add this cast to all description_?_Value columns and try again.

Comment: same error still exist

Comment: @user3751360 when i run `select FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(8.6)+1)))+1 <> 2`
it's giving me error `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

Answer (score 0):

One of the columns you are comparing, either Description_2_Value/Description_3_Value/Description_10_Value is returning that `8.5` value and hence the query is throwing the error while comparing `'8.5' > something`. You need to cast the value RHS value in your condition to a varchar to fix it. See working example below:

```
if ('2.5' > '2')
begin
    print 'success'
end
```